# Convert a Double to an UnSigned Char

Tags: serial, programming, arduino-ide, bluetooth, communication

So, I'm working on **RedBear Blend Micro V 1.0**, and I must use the function:

```
ble_write(Serial.read());
```

To read some input from the serial monitor(*Input being stuff I type in the Serial Monitor*) and send it via bluetooth.
It works perfectly this way!

Now what I need to do is create a random **double** data type number, and insert it in the place of **Serial.read()**

Read This:

### **ble_write**

*Syntax:
    void ble_write(unsigned char data); 
  ble_write sends a single byte data to the BLE Central.*

So, can you please help me, to:

1)Generate a random **double**

2)Send it using the ble_write() function?

For a full list of function sin the ReadBear Library click on the link:
https://github.com/RedBearLab/nRF8001

Comment: If it's random then why not just send random unsigned chars?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for the suggestion but the thing is, for now I want to send a definite NUMBER via the ReadBear BlendMicro, but later, instead of this number, i will be sending data from an ECG Sensor, the data from the ecg sensor is a Double..Dont worry Ive checked the ECG part

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Chris Stratton rightfully points out that the question is
about a `double`, not a `float`:

- a `float` is four bytes in every platform I know about, as per the
  IEEE-754 standard
- a `double` is eight bytes in almost all platforms, with the notable
  exception of AVR: [the AVR double is highly non-standard, four bytes
  long, and essentially equivalent to `float`](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc#Deviations_from_the_Standard)

Most, but not all Arduinos, are AVR-based.
In the following I assume you are talking about AVR doubles, i.e.
floats. If this is not the case, then just replace the array of 4 bytes
by an array of 8 bytes.

---

**Original answer**:
A `float` is four bytes, so it is somewhat equivalent to an array of
four unsigned chars, i.e. to `unsigned char[4]`. You can use this
equivalence with an `union`. For example, the following function will
send a float byte by byte:

```c++
void ble_write_float(float x)
{
    union {
        float f;
        unsigned char c[4];
    } data;

    data.f = x;
    ble_write(data.c[0]);
    ble_write(data.c[1]);
    ble_write(data.c[2]);
    ble_write(data.c[3]);
}
```

Notice that this will send the bytes in whatever is the natural order of
the sending processor. If it's an AVR (like most Arduinos), this will be
LSB (least significant byte) first. You have to make sure that this is
what the receiver expects.

Following Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' suggestion, for sending a random float
you could just send four random bytes. However, it may be wiser to have
an idea of the random distribution you want for your float, and use
things like `random()` and `map()` to achieve that distribution. Using
four random bytes, you get a very wide distribution (all the possible
floats are equally likely) which includes weird things like denormals,
infinities and NaN (literally meaning “not a number”).

Comment: The question asks about a `double` while you answer with regard to a `float` so it would be helpful to mention that on the ATmega based Arduinos they are equivalent, however on some other varieties they are not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Thanks for pointing this out. I amended the answer.